# Empty table causing in NULL in all SELECT fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table, `chat`, that controls what messages have been read from all the other tables. For new users, I am inserting new values.

```
INSERT INTO chat VALUES (1,aaa,bbb,ccc)
SELECT
MAX(chatA.postOrder) AS aaa,
MAX(chatB.postOrder) AS bbb,
MAX(chatC.postOrder) AS ccc
FROM `chatA`, `chatB`, `chatC`
WHERE 1
```

For `ChatB` and `ChatC`, postOrder exists and they both have values. Everything works correctly. Problem is, sometimes a chat is empty (in this case, `chatA`). When this happens, `bbb` and `ccc` become NULL. If I remove this line `MAX(chatA.postOrder) AS aaa,`, the values are still NULL.

I'm stuck here, unable to figure out a way to fix this problem. Changes made in the select field such as `IFNULL(chatA.postOrder,0) AS aaa,` have no effect on the results. It appears that `chatA` in the `FROM` field causes the results of `bbb` and `ccc` to be NULL.

Edit: Formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try union all

```
SELECT MAX(aaa) AS aaa, MAX(bbb) AS bbb, MAX(ccc) AS ccc from (
SELECT MAX(IFNULL(chatA.postOrder,0)) AS aaa, 0 as bbb, 0 AS ccc FROM `chatA`
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS aaa, MAX(IFNULL(chatB.postOrder,0)) AS bbb, 0 AS ccc FROM `chatB`
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS aaa, 0 AS bbb, MAX(IFNULL(chatC.postOrder,0)) AS ccc FROM `chatC`) 
AS derived_table;
```

This is more appropriate because you are not trying to "Join" the tables.  I am assuming the values wont be negative, if they would be then 0 would not be a good number probably a negative number that will never appear in your results would do

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that return a row when any of those tables is empty, you could something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(IF(t.chat='a',t.postOrder,NULL) AS aaa
     , MAX(IF(t.chat='b',t.postOrder,NULL) AS bbb
     , MAX(IF(t.chat='c',t.postOrder,NULL) AS ccc
  FROM ( SELECT 'a' AS `chat`, MAX(ta.postOrder) AS postOrder FROM `chatA` ta
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'b', MAX(tb.postOrder) FROM `chatB` tb
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'c', MAX(tc.postOrder) FROM `chatB` tc
       ) t
```

**NOTES:** The inline view (assigned an alias of `t` above) returns the maximum postOrder from *each* of the three tables. If the table is empty (has no rows), THE SELECT from that table won't return a row. But since the rows will be concatenated together with `UNION ALL` operators. That gives a single result set, which the outer query can select from.  On each of rows, we add a constant literal discriminator (`'a'`, `'b'` or `'c'`) that identifies which table the row was returned from.

The "trick" in the outer query is to test the discriminator column, and return the value for `postOrder` only if that column matches the one specified in the `IF`. Otherwise, we return a NULL. Wrapping that IF() expression in a MAX() aggregate function effectively collapses the three rows into a single row.

---

Your query is effectively:

```
SELECT MAX(a.postOrder) AS aaa
     , MAX(a.postOrder) AS bbb
     , MAX(a.postOrder) AS ccc
  FROM `chatA` a
 CROSS
  JOIN `chatB` b
 CROSS
  JOIN `chatC` c
```

Because of the JOIN operations, if any of those three tables is empty (does not return a row) then the query does not return any row at all.